# SQL - How to find a specific value from DB without going through the entire DB table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wonder how can I find a specific value from DB without going through the entire DB table.
by example:
There is a DB of students and we are looking for all the students with a certain name, how do you do that without going through the whole DB table.

Comment: Do you mean that you have a table of students? Or would you like to find the table in the database that contains the student's names?

Comment: Can you show us how you are going through the whole table ?

Comment: I mean I have a table of students

Comment: And how do you go though it ? With an SQL request ? If so, which one ?

Answer (score 1):

Use INDEXES

> Indexes are used to quickly locate data without having to search every row in a database table every time a database table is accessed. ... Indexes can be created using one or more columns of a database table, providing the basis for both rapid random lookups and efficient access of ordered records.

Comment: Thank you. So for my example how can I create an index based on the column of student's names?

Comment: on which sgbdr are you?

Comment: on Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: `CREATE INDEX index ON table_students (name);`  [here is official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Indexes should be unique, so name is not a good candidate on it's own to form a table index, the DB will not allow you to store 2 students both named 'Jane Smith' for example.

Comment: I think you are talking about unique index not about simple index

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has four options for improving performance for this type of query:

- A regular index (either clustered or non-clustered).
- A full text index.
- Partitioning.
- Hash index (for memory optimized tables).

A regular index, created using [`create index`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), is the "canonical" answer to this question.  It is like an alphabetical list of all names with a pointer to the record.  The implementation uses something called B-trees, so the analogy is not perfect.  These indexes can be used for equality (eg. `=`, `is null`) and inequality comparisons (eg. `in`, `<`, `>`)

A full text index indexes all words in a text column (for some definition of "word").  This can be used for a range of full text search options -- and available through [`contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Partitioning is used when you have lots and lots of data and only a handful of categories.  That is highly unlikely with a `name` in a student database.  But it physically splits the data into separate files for each name or range of names.

Hash-based indexing is only available on memory-optimized tables.  These are only useful for comparisons using `=` and `in` (and `<>` and `not in`).